# Bootstrap 4 Carousel Only Autoplaying Under Certain Conditions

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, create-react-app

I am attempting to implement a Carousel from Bootstrap in my CRA project. I am essentially using the provided code from the documentation:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

It works no problem, the carousel shows up and I am able to scroll through it. However, it does not autoplay when loaded.

Some things I tested that get it to autoplay:

1. I tab over to something else in my web broswer (blank tab or something), have React do a hot reload (put a new line after an import and saving works), then tab back to my development server. This starts the autoplay no problem.
2. Manually clicking through ALL the images on the carousel (in any order - 123, 213, 231, etc.) also starts the autoplay after a slight delay.

I'm stumped, but I have seen that Bootstrap's JavaScript can interfere with React's JavaScript. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the exact same issue with Bootstrap 5.  I think I might try to use jQuery to start the carousel in useEffect or useLayoutEffect.  But that seems a little hackish just to start the carousel when data-bs-ride="carousel" should start it. (bs is used in version 5).

Comment: The problem for me was happening locally (I'm also using Gatsby).  When I deployed to Github with gh-pages the carousel starts automatically but the caption for the next slide appears before the next slide transition on every slide on the first iteration of the carousel.  So, guess I got that new problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you provided in the question, no mention of autoplay... why not use the Bootstrap's built in autoplay mechanism `data-interval="500"` - for the specific duration you need, pass the value from React... No need for us to write the JavaScript

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="500">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! According to the docs, data-ride controls the autoplay from load, not data-interval. Data-interval is defaulted to 5000 and controls the speed so this is not the issue. My top level div for the carousel contains everything you had indicated unfortunately: <div className='carousel slide' id='carouselExampleIndicators' data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">